# asmack presence only for a few with roster listener?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I am working on a chat application and implemented a rosterlistener to get changed presence. But I am getting from all of my rosters presence update.

This is how far I got..

How I change presence:

```
public void setStatus(boolean available, String status) {

    Presence.Type type = available ? Type.available : Type.unavailable;
    Presence presence = new Presence(type);

    presence.setStatus(status);
    connection.sendPacket(presence);

}
```

How I listen for changing presence:

```
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {

    public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> param) {
    }

    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {
    }

    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {
    }

    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {

        /* Do something when presence changed */

    });
```

Is there a way to send presence change like status only for selected rosters ?

Comment: What do you mean by "only for selected rosters?". Do you want to send a presence only to a subset of the entries of your roster?

Comment: yes, I have my roster list but I dont want that everybody to get my presence only those who I will select from a menu option. That's the theory, I dont know if it's possible.

Comment: hi @cesztoszule, how to send presence change like status only. Plz help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be controlled with [XEP-0016: Privacy Lists](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html)

I don't know whether smack supports this though.